# Subclass URLSession iOS 10

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I'm trying to subclass `URLSession` on iOS 10 using Xcode 8. I believe the Swift type system is getting confused, but I may be missing something:

```
class MyURLSession: URLSession {

// No errors
override func downloadTask(with request: URLRequest) -> URLSessionDownloadTask {
    return URLSessionDownloadTask()
}

// No errors
override func downloadTask(with url: URL) -> URLSessionDownloadTask {
    return URLSessionDownloadTask()
}

// See errors below
override func downloadTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDownloadTask {
    return URLSessionDownloadTask()
}

// See errors below
override func downloadTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDownloadTask {
    return URLSessionDownloadTask()
}
}



error: method does not override any method from its superclass
    override func downloadTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDownloadTask {
                  ^
Foundation.URLSession:6:15: note: potential overridden instance method 'downloadTask(with:completionHandler:)' here
    open func downloadTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) -> URLSessionDownloadTask
              ^
Foundation.URLSession:7:15: note: potential overridden instance method 'downloadTask(with:completionHandler:)' here
    open func downloadTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) -> URLSessionDownloadTask
              ^
/Users/pshah/Networking/Webservice.swift:108:19: error: method does not override any method from its superclass
    override func downloadTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDownloadTask {
                  ^
Foundation.URLSession:6:15: note: potential overridden instance method 'downloadTask(with:completionHandler:)' here
    open func downloadTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) -> URLSessionDownloadTask
              ^
Foundation.URLSession:7:15: note: potential overridden instance method 'downloadTask(with:completionHandler:)' here
    open func downloadTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) -> URLSessionDownloadTask
              ^
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I have a `Error` in my project, so had to qualify `Error?` as `Swift.Error?` in the methods with errors.